# How to shorten my url using .htaccess file

Tags: html, .htaccess, url

My url:

```
www.example.com/about/about_me.html
```

I want it to look like this and open the about_me.html file

```
www.example.com/about
```

I want to search for my domain name followed by the /about and the page that opens is the about_me.html. I want to do this with my htacess file. And another thing is where i place my .htacess file in my server

Comment: "/about" - do you specifically want the URL without a trailing slash? This does complicate things a bit since `/about` would seem to be a physical directory on the filesystem. It would be preferable to use `/about/` (with a trailing slash) in this instance.

Comment: i want the url to be /about only. This is for my portfolio so i want the user to type: "www.example.com/about" to see the about me page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is made more complicated because `/about` maps to a physical directory on the filesystem. Ordinarily, mod_dir will append the trailing slash (with a 301 redirect) in order to "fix" the URL. To prevent this we need to disable this behaviour, however, there are potential caveats and security implications with doing this. If this is disabled, you may need to manually override this elsewhere on the system.

Try the following in the root `.htaccess` file:

```
# Disable directory listings (mod_autoindex)
Options -Indexes

# Prevent mod_dir appending the trailing slash
DirectorySlash Off

# Enable the rewrite engine (mod_rewrite)
RewriteEngine On

# Internally rewrite "/about" to "/about/about_me.html"
RewriteRule ^about$ about/about_me.html [L]
```

Now, a request for `/about` will serve `/about/about_me.html`. But a request for `/about/` (with a trailing slash) will result in a 403 Forbidden (assuming there is no `DirectoryIndex` document in the `/about` subdirectory).

And requesting any other directory without a trailing slash (eg. `/subdirectory`) will also result in a 403 Forbidden, regardless of whether there is a `DiretcoryIndex` document present in that directory or not.

mod_autoindex needs to be disabled (ie. `Options -Indexes`) in order to prevent accidental information disclosure when `DirectorySlash Off` is set. See the relevant Apache manual page for `DirectorySlash`: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash

---

To make life easier, avoid using URLs (without a trailing slash) that map directly to filesystem directories. For example, you could store all your content in a `/content` subdirectory, then the `/about` URL maps to `/content/about/about_me.html` instead. You then don't need to disable `DirectorySlash` (and it's trivial to block direct access to the `/content` if you need to).

For example:

```
# Enable the rewrite engine (mod_rewrite)
RewriteEngine On

# Internally rewrite "/about" to "/content/about/about_me.html"
RewriteRule ^about$ content/about/about_me.html [L]
```

Comment: That you MrWhite the answer was useful and it worked fine with me and thank you very much for your help